# Django views: how to modify returned queryset before rendering in template?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, graph

I'm trying to make a simple weather JSON API with Python 2.7 and Django 1.5.

My WeatherData model looks like this:

```
class WeatherData(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    temp_f = models.DecimalField()
```

**In my views, I want to convert the `created_at` datetime object stored by Django into UTC seconds.** (I understand there will be a timezone problem.)

I already know how to convert a datetime object (named `MYTIME`) to seconds:

```
import time
time.mktime(MYTIME.timetuple())
```

However, when I define the `queryset = WeatherData.objects.all()` I can't figure out a way to convert these datetime objects on-the-fly to UTC seconds while maintaining the queryset object. **In short, I want to modify a returned queryset in the views before rendering in template.**

I'm new to using Django and MySQL but I imagine there's a way to do this.

Note: I'm using [TastyPie](http://tastypieapi.org), so I don't have direct access to a template file. I specify the queryset fields in a ModelResource class:

```
class WeatherResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = WeatherData.objects.all()
        fields = ['created_at' 'temp_f']
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to modify the data solely for the purpose of rendering it in your template, or is it so you can then perform other operations (i.e. sorting, choosing a template dynamically, etc.)? If it's the former, you won't want to modify the queryset at all ... rather you'd use a template tag that would do the conversion at the time of rendering. If it's the latter, then there are several approaches you could try. Provide a bit more of the context to get some specific solutions.

Comment: It's just for rendering. Specifically, I need to serialize the datetime object into JSON. But since I'm using TastyPie, I don't have access to the template file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to modify it, just add a method to the `WeatherData` class that do this and call the method within the template for each object in the query set:

```
import time
class WeatherData(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    temp_f = models.DecimalField()

    def created_at_utc(self):
        # whatever logic you need to do the conversion
        return time.mktime(self.created_at.timetuple())
```

and within your template do this:

```
{% for data in deatherdata %}
    data.created_at_utc
{% endfor %}
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Awesome, thanks, this works great! One question though: I'm rendering my API template using TastyPie (http://tastypieapi.org/), so I don't have access to the template file. How can I insert this field into the TastyPie `ModelResource` view class? (I edited my post so it now includes the code.)

Comment: I haven't used Tastypie but I think this link will be good for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13539901/how-to-change-tastypie-time-format

Comment: As well as this: https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/docs/cookbook.rst Good luck! :)